# 2D List (row total/grand total) in Python

Tags: python

My question is about obtaining the sum of each row in a 2d list and then obtaining the total of all rows. Below is the information given to me--

We will pass in a 2 dimensional list of numbers.
You should:

*add up all the numbers in each row and output that number

*output the grand total of all rows

this is the code given to me:

```
# Get our list from the command line arguments
import sys
numbers= sys.argv[1:]

# Convert the command line arguments into 2d list
for i in range(0,len(numbers)): 
    numbers[i]= numbers[i].split(',')
```

This work is completed via Codio. When I print my 2d list this is the output I get:

```
print(numbers)
[['1', '1', '-2'], ['-1', '-2', '-3'], ['1', '1', '1']]
```

Based on previous problems and scenarios I have worked, these numbers have changed based on the coding I have developed to make sure it meets all the guidelines of the assignment.

I have tried various attempts at the problem, listed below:

```
row = len(numbers)
column = len(numbers[0])
total = 0

for row in numbers:
    rowtotal = 0
    for column in numbers:
        rowtotal = rowtotal + numbers[row][column]
        print(rowtotal)
        total = total + rowtotal
print(total)
```

This gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 17, in 
    rowtotal = rowtotal + numbers[row][column]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

I have also tried:

```
row = len(numbers)
column = len(numbers[0])
total = 0

for row in range (len(numbers)):
    for col in range(len(numbers[0])):
        total = total + numbers[row][column]
print(total)
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 16, in 
    total = total + numbers[row][column]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

For my last attempt I tried:

```
total = 0
for x in range (0, len(numbers)):
    rowtotal = 0
    for y in range (0, len(numbers[0])):
        rowtotal = rowtotal = int(numbers[x][y])
    print(rowtotal)
    total = total + rowtotal
print(total)
```

Which finally gave me numbers, but not the correct ones:

```
Program Failed for Input: 1,1,-2 -1,-2,-3 1,1,1
Expected Output: 0
-6
 3
-3
Your Program Output: -2
-3
 1
-4
```

If I could get any help I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: On your second attempt, in `total = total + numbers[row][column]` change `column` for `col`. And convert the numbers (that are `str`, you can't sum a int with a str) to `int`. Something like `total = total + int(numbers[row][col])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's instructional to break down your attempts one by one and talk about what went wrong in each one.

For starters, your input list is a 2-dimensional list of numbers *as strings*. You'll need to cast them to `int`, preferably right off the bat. However, I'll assume the input list you're working with in your code is the following:

```
[['1', '1', '-2'], ['-1', '-2', '-3'], ['1', '1', '1']]
```

which needs its elements to be cast to `int` to avoid crashing.

---

### Attempt 1

Your code:

```
row = len(numbers)
column = len(numbers[0])
total = 0

for row in numbers:
    rowtotal = 0
    for column in numbers: # <-- are these really columns as advertised or still rows?
        rowtotal = rowtotal + numbers[row][column] # <-- crash!
        print(rowtotal)
        total = total + rowtotal # <-- are you sure you want to do this here?
print(total)
```

The primary misunderstanding is that your statement `for row in numbers:` loops through the *actual lists* in the `numbers` list, not the indices of this list. In other words, `row` is equal to `['1', '1', '-2']` on the first iteration, not `0`.

Similarly, `for column in numbers:` is mis-labeled and also iterates over row lists rather than the intended cells in rows. The crash happens when you try to index into the list `numbers` using these items. Your code is doing:

```
numbers[['1', '1', '-2']][['1', '1', '-2']] # crash
```

You can fix this by not attempting to index into the `numbers` list, but instead using the `row` and `column` elements to compute the total.

You also have a logic error that prematurely adds `rowtotal` to the aggregate `total`, which over counts.

Lastly, the first two lines do nothing because the values are overwritten by the loop variables; remove them.

Here's a re-write:

```
total = 0

for row in numbers:
    rowtotal = 0

    for column in row: # <-- iterating cells in rows
        rowtotal = rowtotal + int(column) # <-- much better
        
    total = total + rowtotal # <-- logic error fixed

print(total)
```

---

### Attempt 2

Your code:

```
row = len(numbers)
column = len(numbers[0])
total = 0

for row in range (len(numbers)):
    for col in range(len(numbers[0])):
        total = total + numbers[row][column] # <-- crash!
print(total)
```

Similar problem here as the first. You have two lines at the beginning that introduce the variables `row` and `column`. When you write `for row in range(len(numbers)):` you overwrite the `row` variable you initialized on line 1.

However, when you write `for col in range(len(numbers[0])):`, you *don't* overwrite `column` and you attempt to index into `numbers` using the out of bounds `column` variable, which stores the length of the list, crashing the program.

Of course, don't forget to cast to `int` if you haven't already done so.

Fixed:

```
total = 0

for row in range(len(numbers)):
    for col in range(len(numbers[row])): # added row here in case of a ragged list
        total += int(numbers[row][col])

print(total)
```

---

### Attempt 3

Your code:

```
total = 0
for x in range (0, len(numbers)):
    rowtotal = 0
    for y in range (0, len(numbers[0])):
        rowtotal = rowtotal = int(numbers[x][y]) # <-- typo! = should be +
    print(rowtotal)
    total = total + rowtotal
print(total)
```

So close! The issue here is that you've used the wrong operator, `=` when you meant `+`. I recommend using the `+=` operator going forward, which adds the right hand side expression to the left hand side variable and stores it in the left hand side variable.

Fixed:

```
total = 0

for x in range (0, len(numbers)):
    rowtotal = 0

    for y in range (0, len(numbers[0])):
        rowtotal = rowtotal + int(numbers[x][y]) # or use rowtotal += int(numbers[x][y])

    total += rowtotal

print(total)
```

---

### My version

Here's how I'd write this:

```
print(sum([sum([int(n) for n in row]) for row in numbers]))
```

This uses something called a list comprehension, which is basically a one-line `for` loop that creates a list. The inner list comprehension `sum([int(n) for n in row])` gives you the total for a row and the outer comprehension makes a list of all row totals, passing these totals into the outmost call to `sum`.

Don't stress if this is confusing--the important part is learning how to [debug your existing programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), which is all about evaluating your assumptions step by step and walking through your logic in small chunks. When you have a crash and a printed stack trace, that's good--it tells you exactly what went wrong and where to look. If that still doesn't make the situation clear, simplify your code to a point where it works and you understand your program state, then build up again.

Comment: sum(map(int, row)) better imo. No need to feed a list to sum.

Comment: Good call. I forget about `map`.

Comment: You can also get rid of the square brackets and use a generator expression.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used my attempt 1  with the information you provided, it passed :)

Comment: @jpp We haven't used map in our studies yet so I don't really feel comfortable using that technique yet, but thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I am new to the site so I wasn't able to comment on the users answer that was marked as accepted but I noticed an issue in the code. It was only outputting one part of the question that was asked. The original code was:

```
total = 0

for row in numbers:
    rowtotal = 0

   for column in row:  
       rowtotal = rowtotal + int(column) 

total = total + rowtotal  

print(total)
```

But it also needed to print the "rowtotal" so the answer to the question would be one more line of code like this:

```
total = 0

for row in numbers:
    rowtotal = 0

   for column in row: 
       rowtotal = rowtotal + int(column) 
   print(rowtotal) # <---- New line of code
total = total + rowtotal 

print(total)
```

Now it would be able to pass in your Codio environment as both outputs would print.1) the total of each row and 2) the grand total of all rows. I hope this is helpful to anyone who is also using the Codio IDE for their classes and come across this challenge. As always there is ways to simplify the code, but if your at this stage in your course it is probably beyond the scope that you have reached.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage python [list comprehension](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) and the built-in sum function to do this quite easily:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
row_totals = [sum(row) for row in matrix]
grand_total = sum(row_totals)
```

Or, you could use vanilla loops and addition:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
row_totals = []
grand_total = 0
for row in matrix:
    row_total = 0
    for value in row:
        row_total += value
    row_totals.append(row_total)
    grand_total += row_total
```

Comment: I get the below error when I use the loop example you have provided:

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "list.py", line 16, in 
        row_total += value
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: If the items in the list are strings and not integers, then you need to cast them to integers first, using `int(value)`